# why cheerio.load() function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const HTML = `<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>
        Team Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Year
    </th>
    <th>
        Wins
    </th>
    <th>
        Losses
    </th>
</tr>
</tbody>
`;

const $ = cheerio.load(HTML);
const text = $('tr').text();
console.log(text);
```

Here I am not getting a text. Why??
Is there any error in the HTML string?
I am not able to identify the issue. Please help!!!

Comment: it works: https://runkit.com/embed/oqy40kkxmhn5

Comment: @marzelin — It works in cheerio@0.22 but not in cheerio@1.0.0

Answer (score 6):

A `<tbody>` element must be a child of a `<table>` element and yours isn't.

In the current version of Cheerio the parser doesn't recover from that error. Write valid HTML. (Wrapping your string in `<table>` and `</table>` is sufficient).

(If you downgrade to Cheerio 0.22.0 then the parser there can handle it, but fixing the input is preferred to using out of date libraries).